# PaintEvent triggered couple times my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, paintevent

I dont understand why PaintEvent perfoming my code three and more time... Why and where it's initianilised so many times? Is it real repainting so many times and why?

```
def dispTabs(self):         
    self.w = MyPopup1()
    self.ui.tabWidget.addTab(self.w, 'Test')


class MyPopup1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)   
        print 'ok'

    def paintEvent(self, event): 
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        print 'ok 2'
        color = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
        color.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(color)

        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)
```

Output:

```
ok
ok2
ok2
ok2
```

Later may added more 'ok2'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paintEvent method is called every time the GUI is required to be repainted, and this is called many times for example when you first display the widget, when you move the widget, when you hover your mouse over the widget, etc. The XEvent methods should not be called directly but are invoked by events handled by Qt, that is, Qt decides when it needs to be called, in this case Qt analyzes when it is necessary to repaint.

Comment: So, this is normal behaviour of application when at one call my script paintEvent triggered three times at once? It's really possible, even at once? I dont need to somehow check it and try optimize?

Huh, I spent so many time to find my misstake but it not misstake...

Comment: @VadymHoncharuk It is normal behavior, that part is already optimized, and you cannot change this behavior, your code is correct